# C++ use cin.get to get a character, but not end the while loop when encounter the EOF

Tags: c++, eof

The following is my code, that I want to read characters from stdin, and end when it meet an EOF(ctrl-z).

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string article ;    
    char nextChar;
    while( cin.get(nextChar) ) {
        if( cin.eof() ) break ;
        article.append(1, nextChar) ;
    }

    cout << article ;

    system("pause") ;
}
```

I test an input like this:

```
I am a student.<ctrl-z>
```

And then I press enter, but it does not halt.

When I type another [ctrl-z], and then press neter.

It just can exit from the while loop.

Why the first [ctrl-z] not to signal the eof condition?

Comment: Try `Ctrl-D` for `EOF`. (`Ctrl-Z` is often "pause the process").

Comment: @Galik: That's highly environment-specific.  ASCII 26 is an EOF marker, but terminals on OSes other than Windows don't usually generate ASCII 26 when Ctrl+Z is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

The following explanation is slightly simplified.

It's a feature of your operating system. This is how your operating system works.

An end of file is, really, the underlying `read()` system call returning 0. An end of file is not `CTRL-Z`. `CTRL-Z` gets interpreted by your operating system to flush its interactive key buffer, and have the process `read()` its contents.

When you type in a terminal, the process does not actually end up reading anything until `Enter` is pressed. At that time the `read()` system call completes, and returns everything that's been read. In general, before pressing `Enter` you can backspace and edit what you typed, and your program has no indication that you've edited anything, all that it `read`()s is the final contents of the line after pressing `Enter`.

If you type something, and press `CTRL-Z`, the typed input is also `read`() by the program as if it was typed in.

Only if nothing is typed, and `CTRL-Z` is pressed, does the underlying `read()` system call returns 0, because nothing got typed in first; this is interpreted as an end-of-file indication. But if something gets typed in first, `CTRL-Z` needs to be entered twice, once to `read()` the typed in input, and clear the input buffer, then `CTRL-Z` a second time, to cause an `read`() of 0.

By the way, your code has a harmless bug. If `cin.get()` succeeds, `cin.eof()` can never be true.